# Image won't align with top of div

Tags: html, css, image, web

I am making a website theme for a friend and I can't seem to get the image in the third div to touch the top, any ideas on why this is happening? Demo of site: http://blindersjournal.pancakeapps.com/indexblinders.html/

CSS:

```
        .one {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/A2Eps8D.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 65px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    @font-face {
    font-family: Nexa;
    src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/Nexa%20Bold.otf');
    }
    .navlinks li { 
    font-family: Nexa;
    font-size: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 125px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 63px;
    display: inline;
    }
    nav img {
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    }
    * { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    border: none; 
    }
    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    }
    .two {
    background-color: black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .twoimg img {
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    }
    .twoimg {
    float: left;
    }
    article {
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 25px;
    }
    .name {
    font-family: Nexa;
    font-size: 20px;
    }
    .three {
    background-color: black;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .threeimg img {
    height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    }
    .threeimg {
    float: right;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<link href="/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/indexblinders.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Blinders Journal</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="one">
<nav>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/zkED7Bc.png" />
<div class="navlinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Masthead</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="two">        
<div class="twoimg">
<img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Lisa.JPG" />
</div>
<article>
<p><span class="name">Lisa Beth Fulgham</span> is a recent graduate of Mississippi State University's M.A. program in creative writing and is the Managing/Founding Editor of Blinders Literary Journal. Currently, she is a wanderer and is working on submitting her chapbook, A Voice Raised From the Dirt. She is the former Associate Editor of The Jabberwock Review, and she is a fan of Southern Gothic literature or basically anything that gives her the creeps.</p>
</article>
</div>
<div class="three">        
<article>
<p><span class="name">Rachel M. Rice</span> is the Nonfiction Editor of Blinders Literary Journal. A soon-to-be graduate of Mississippi State University's M.A. program, she is currently working on a collection of short stories about living as an LGBTQ person on the Mississippi Gulf Coast. As soon as she graduates, she'll be joining her husband, buying a house, adopting a dog, and generally, being an adult.</p>
</article> 
<div class="threeimg">
<img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Rachel.JPG" />
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
var $bgobj = $(this);
$(window).scroll(function() {
var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));        
var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
$bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
});
});   
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.three` and give `.threeimg` the following CSS:

```
.threeimg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

No need for `float`

Comment: allright! thanks for all the help guys! this has far been my most successful thread and all of you guys are to thank!

Answer (score 0):

Try this css (from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt0j59jw/1/)

```
<body>
<div class="one">
<nav>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/zkED7Bc.png" />
<div class="navlinks">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Submissions</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Masthead</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="two">        
<div class="twoimg">
<img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Lisa.JPG" />
</div>

<article>
<p><span class="name">Lisa Beth Fulgham</span> is a recent graduate of Mississippi State University's M.A. program in creative writing and is the Managing/Founding Editor of Blinders Literary Journal. Currently, she is a wanderer and is working on submitting her chapbook, A Voice Raised From the Dirt. She is the former Associate Editor of The Jabberwock Review, and she is a fan of Southern Gothic literature or basically anything that gives her the creeps.</p>
</article>
</div>
<div class="three">        
<article>
<p><img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Rachel.JPG" class="threeimg" /><span class="name">Rachel M. Rice</span> is the Nonfiction Editor of Blinders Literary Journal. A soon-to-be graduate of Mississippi State University's M.A. program, she is currently working on a collection of short stories about living as an LGBTQ person on the Mississippi Gulf Coast. As soon as she graduates, she'll be joining her husband, buying a house, adopting a dog, and generally, being an adult.
</p> 

</article>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('section[data-type="background"]').each(function(){
var $bgobj = $(this);
$(window).scroll(function() {
var yPos = -($window.scrollTop() / $bgobj.data('speed'));        
var coords = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
$bgobj.css({ backgroundPosition: coords });
});
});   
});
</script>
</body>
```

css

```
.one {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/A2Eps8D.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
min-height: 65px;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
@font-face {
font-family: Nexa;
src: url('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/105222237/Nexa%20Bold.otf');
}
.navlinks li { 
font-family: Nexa;
font-size: 20px;
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding-left: 125px;
vertical-align: middle;
line-height: 63px;
display: inline;
}
nav img {
float: left;
height: 60px;
}
* { 
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border: none; 
}
a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #fff;
}
.two {
background-color: black;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.twoimg img {
height: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
}
.twoimg {
float: left;
}
article {
max-width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
color: #fff;
margin-top: 25px;
}
.name {
font-family: Nexa;
font-size: 20px;
}
.three {
background-color: black;
max-height: 200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.threeimg {
float: right;
height: 200px;
max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: I think OP wants the image to float next to the Rachels info

Comment: No, I want the second image to align with the top of the third div, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yep. Sorry again for the confusion.

Comment: Hey @8bitcodecat, I made an update here, should fix it I think.

Comment: It works in the fiddle, you must have copied something wrong. I didn't include the stylesheets in the jsfiddle, maybe your css is overriding the fix I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This will make the second image to align to the bottom of the first one, with the rachel Article.
Try cutting

`<div class="threeimg">
<img src="http://blindersjournal.org/img/Rachel.JPG" />
</div>`

and pasting it Above it's `<article>`

Is that what you want? Demo here (edit 3): http://jsfiddle.net/ca9yfssu/3/
Last Edit comment: Editted to make the 3rd image to fully match the 2nd even if the window is resized.

Comment: Editted it once more to have some space to the right to match the second image: http://jsfiddle.net/ca9yfssu/2/

Comment: Editted once more to fully match the second image even if the window is resized. http://jsfiddle.net/ca9yfssu/3/